# Parsing data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, i need to parse this data from firebase to use on my quiz app made with react. The goal is get the infos and questions from firebse. I already did this steps:

```
const data = snapshot.val()
const parsedData = Object.entries(data).map((value) => {
    return value
})
```

The result i've got is this:

[image: Console log message]

I dont know how to proceed... Any tips?

Comment: need more clarity, can you specify your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeing the result you have got the `object` you have is

```
{
 author:"pedro..",
 info: '..',
 questions: "..."
}
```

If you only need the questions and info for storing them in a sate

**Your approach, you can use like this**

```
const [question, setQuestion] = useState([])
const [info, setInfo] = useState('')

const data = snapshot.val()
Object.keys(data).map((value) => {
    if (value === "info"){
       setInfo(data?.value ?? "")
    }
    if(value === "questions"){
       setQuestions(data?.questions ?? [])
    }
})
```